# jQuery click function work but live click not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, click, live

i am trying to run a live click function in jQuery and found that's not work like

```
$(function () {
    $("#elem #check").click(function () {
        alert('goaa');
    });
    $("#elem #check").live("click", function () {
        alert('fo');
    });

});
```

the page load and nothing come from ajax.when i trying to run that i found that [click] first is work and second not [live click].

what is the reason of click are work and live not worked.:-

Well it is my fault that i am trying to run it on jQuery UI tab so that's not worked.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to bind 2 click handlers if you want the same behavior in each -- just the `live()` is fine: `$("#elem #check").live("click", function () {});`

Answer (score 3):

No idea what the problem is. As you can see in the [following live demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke5AB/) this code works perfectly fine.

Comment: sorry for posting i am trying on jQuery UI based tab.

Answer (score 0):

probably somewhere for your selector or on parent elements click event stopped 
for ex `$("#elem")` or on parent

```
$("#check").live("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagiation();
    });
```

in oter place stopped event bubbling and capture

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, live function works perfectly in a dynamic loaded content. But it is not working on recent JQuery file. But you can use another function: https://api.jquery.com/delegate/