# Jquery ajax call not going into success or error function on second run

Tags: php, jquery

I am running an ajax call and it works perfectly the first time it runs but I call it again on a click function and firebug shows that it does not step into the error function or the success function.  Isn't that how success and error works? Is there a reason why the code would not go into either the success or the error function?

```
    $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "chat_new_files/chat_new.php",

                        success: function(data){                
                        if(data != "false"){
                        $(".chat").attr("onclick", "clickFunction()");


                            $(".chat").attr('id','chatT');
                            $(".chat").attr('src', 'chat_new_files/images/button_active_noclick.jpg');
                            $("#noRepsMes").text('');
                            return "true";
                            }
                            else{
                                $(".chat").attr('src','chat_new_files/images/button_inactive.jpg');
                                $("#noRepsMes").text('There are no available representatives.');
                                $(".chat").attr('onclick', '');
                                $(".chat").attr('id', 'chatF');

                                return "false";
                            }
                        },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                                        alert(err.Message);
                                    }
        });

function clickFunction() {
                            avail = checkReps();
                            if(avail == "true"){
                                BG.startChatWithIssueId('0', true);
                            }
                            else
                                alert("There are no available representatives.");
                        }
```

SORRY SIMPLE NOOB MISTAKE:   It was because of scope. I will add what i did to fix it once I have the right to answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code, I get ... **nothing**!

However, when I make the following modification, I get **something**!

```
     $("#noRepsMes").text('');
     console.log("success"); // i love debugging
     return "true";
```

So, it is going into the success function...

**Edit**

May be pertinent for you to post your other code relating to the click event ...

[jQuery click function work but live click not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913636/jquery-click-function-work-but-live-click-not-work)

Comment: ok I added my click function and the click function is called within the html of the button. <img id="chatT" class="chat" border="0" align="absbottom" style="padding-top: 10px;" alt="Chat Now" src="chat_new_files/images/button_active_noclick.jpg" onclick="clickFunction()">